# UIDefaults.getUI() failed: error when loading a JFrame into another project

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I found [this project](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JSliderExamples1.html) which works just fine in a standalone run. However when I try to add it to a JPanel in another project (already did this in the exact same project but with a JFrame of my own and worked fine) this error arises:

```
 UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: doubleslider.MThumbSlider[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isInverted=false,majorTickSpacing=0,minorTickSpacing=0,orientation=HORIZONTAL,paintLabels=false,paintTicks=false,paintTrack=true,snapToTicks=false,snapToValue=true]
    java.lang.Error
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:729)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:759)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1002)
        at javax.swing.JSlider.updateUI(JSlider.java:323)
        at doubleslider.MThumbSlider.updateUI(MThumbSlider.java:44)
        at javax.swing.JSlider.<init>(JSlider.java:275)
        at javax.swing.JSlider.<init>(JSlider.java:182)
        at doubleslider.MThumbSlider.<init>(MThumbSlider.java:24)
        at doubleslider.DoubleSlider.<init>(DoubleSlider.java:29)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.Ventana.<init>(Ventana.java:227)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.ScadaRemoteControl.<init>(ScadaRemoteControl.java:92)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.ScadaRemoteControl.main(ScadaRemoteControl.java:197)
    UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: doubleslider.MThumbSlider[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isInverted=false,majorTickSpacing=0,minorTickSpacing=0,orientation=HORIZONTAL,paintLabels=false,paintTicks=false,paintTrack=true,snapToTicks=false,snapToValue=true]
    java.lang.Error
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:729)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:130)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:759)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1002)
        at javax.swing.JSlider.updateUI(JSlider.java:323)
        at doubleslider.MThumbSlider.updateUI(MThumbSlider.java:44)
        at doubleslider.MThumbSlider.<init>(MThumbSlider.java:26)
        at doubleslider.DoubleSlider.<init>(DoubleSlider.java:29)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.Ventana.<init>(Ventana.java:227)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.ScadaRemoteControl.<init>(ScadaRemoteControl.java:92)
        at com.einge.scadaremotecontrol.ScadaRemoteControl.main(ScadaRemoteControl.java:197)
```

My first guess is that the MultiTumbSlider class is trying to set a different Look&Feel than my JFrame. Any solutions? I couldn't figure this out and I really need two sliders so to have a time Range

Any help will be appretiated!

Comment: What look & feel are you using?

Comment: @trashgod , I imported the working project as a jar file so no package problems should arise.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using the Windows L&F and I suspect the MThumbSlider project is using some "Metal" L&F

Comment: That's what I suspect as well

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognize the loading approach used in this very old [example](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JSliderExamples1.html); it appear to be based on the current Look & Feel. You might try setting `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel` explicitly. Going forward, look at Kirill Grouchnikov's [*How to Write a Custom Swing Component*](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html) for guidance on modernizing the delegate plumbing.

Comment: I played around with updateUI() method found on the MThumbSlider class to load the L&F. With that I manage to get rid of the error but still the slider is missing in my program. The only way I found to make this slider appear is using a button to show up another JFrame with the slider, that and changing my program's L&F to metal did work. But I want to show the slider inside a JPanel in my main window. I am giving up this example as it took several hours and nothing concrete is coming. Do you have any other approaches to make a double Slider (or a "range" slider)?

Comment: I followed Kirill's guide successfully. Sorry I have nothing better.

Comment: A related example from that archive is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18242040/230513).

Answer (score 1):

At the book "Java Swing, 2nd Edition", by Marc Loy et. al., at the section "Creating Your Own Component" (Chapter 28: Swing Under the Hood), we have the code line at the `main()` method:

```
UIManager.put(JogShuttleUI.UI_CLASS_ID, "BasicJogShuttleUI");
```

This will inform the `UIDefaults`, through `UIManeger`, the class name of the basic UI delegate of the custom component. Note, however, that you must provide the *fully qualified class name*, since it will be located by the class loading mechanism.

For example, when I'm use

```
UIManager.put(DiagramUI.UI_CLASS_ID, "BasicDiagramUI");
```

I get the same error reported by your question. But, when I change it to

```
UIManager.put(DiagramUI.UI_CLASS_ID, BasicDiagramUI.class.getName());
```

Things works pretty well. Nice coding!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Helped a lot